# How to I use collect/reduce operator with the first value as a accumulator in RxJava?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I've got

```
class Player {
           PUID playerId;
           PUID teamId;
           int numOfScoredPoints;
}
```

So what I really want to write is:

```
collect(
   (a) -> a,
   (acc, player) -> acc.numOfScoredPoints += player.numOfScoredPoints
)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the `reduce(BiFunction)` that does not use an initial value:

```
source.reduce((acc, player) -> {
    acc.numOfScoredPoints += player.numOfScoredPoints;
    return acc;
});
```

just keep returning the first argument.

Comment: IDEA says it's going to return Maybe<Player> and I'd like to return Single<Player>. Is there any workaround about it?

Comment: Use `toSingle`.